# Read multiple hash keys and keep only unique values

Tags: puppet

If I have data in Hiera like:

```yaml
resource_adapter_instances:
  'Adp1':
    adapter_plan_dir: "/opt/weblogic/middleware"
    adapter_plan:     'Plan_DB.xml'
  'Adp2':
    adapter_plan_dir: "/opt/weblogic/middleware"
    adapter_plan:     'ODB_Plan_DB.xml'
  'Adp3':
    adapter_plan_dir: "/opt/weblogic/middleware"
    adapter_plan:     'Plan_DB.xml'
```

And I need to transform this into an array like this, noting duplicates are removed:

```
[/opt/weblogic/middleware/Plan_DB.xml, /opt/weblogic/middleware/ODB_Plan_DB.xml]
```

I know I have to use Puppet's [map](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/function.html#map) but I am really struggling with it.

I tried this:

```puppet
$resource_adapter_instances = hiera('resource_adapter_instances', {})
$resource_adapter_paths = $resource_adapter_instances.map |$h|{$h['adapter_plan_dir']},{$h['adapter_plan']}.join('/').uniq
notice($resource_adapter_instances)
```

But that doesn't work, and emits syntax errors. How do I do this?

Comment: `hiera.values.map { |h| [h[:adapter_plan_dir] , h[:adapter_plan]].join('/') }.uniq`

Comment: I've removed the Ruby tag, nothing to do with Ruby.

Comment: @DaveShaw, you'll need to say clearly what it is you're actually trying to do, and if possible, fix the syntax errors and indenting because we can't read it. puppet parser vallidate your_file.pp.

Comment: Also, the version of Puppet you're using, since it appears to be an old one.

Comment: Thanks @AlexHarvey - I'm not sure how the desired output isn't clear, happy to edit it though.  It says "the result I'm looking for..." - we're using puppet 5

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin - I think you're very close.  I've looked at the map documentation https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/function.html#map and can see the format has changed, so I'm trying this, it doesn't like the commat though.

```
$resource_adapter_paths = $resource_adapter_instances.map |$h| {$h['adapter_plan_dir'],$h['adapter_plan']}.join('/').uniq
```

Comment: @DaveShaw Aleksei has given you Ruby code, because you added a Ruby tag. :)

Comment: Thanks @AlexHarvey, I appreciate anyone taking even  a few seconds to help a stranger out on the internet.  I've updated so hopefully that's a little clearer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. A possible solution is as follows:

```puppet
$resource_adapter_instances = lookup('resource_adapter_instances', {})
$resource_adapter_paths =
  $resource_adapter_instances.map |$x| {
    [$x[1]['adapter_plan_dir'], $x[1]['adapter_plan']].join('/')
  }
  .unique
notice($resource_adapter_paths)
```

A few further notes:

- The hiera function is [deprecated](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.2/hiera_use_hiera_functions.html) so I rewrote using lookup and you should too.
- Puppet's map function can be a little confusing - especially if you need to iterate with it through a nested Hash, as in your case. On each iteration, Puppet passes each key and value pair as an array in the form `[key, value]`. Thus, $x[0] gets your Hash key (Adp1 etc) and $x[1] gets the data on the right hand side.
- Puppet's unique function is not `uniq` as in Bash, Ruby etc but actually is spelt out as `unique`.
- Note I've rewritten it without the massively long lines. It's much easier to read.

If you puppet apply that you'll get:

```
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): [/opt/weblogic/middleware/Plan_DB.xml,
  /opt/weblogic/middleware/ODB_Plan_DB.xml]
```

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I've been converting our manifests from hiera to lookup where I've come across it.  We have quite a lot of old code on site.
Thanks for the pointers too.  Very much appreciated, I;ve been working with puppet a while but this is the first time I've really had to dig into subkeys.  I think some training in that area is needed.
Thanks once again!